# Big O notation O(n²)

Tags: math, big-o

I want to know, why this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) for 1+2+3+...+n?

For example, 1+2+3+4 = 4·(4+1)/2 = 10 but 4<sup>2</sup>=16, so how come it's O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: you need to look at definition of `O`-notation deeper.

Comment: Do you know the closed-form expression for the sum of the first `n` integers? The trend for how the sum grows as `n` gets bigger isn't obvious from only two data points.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: @chepner: You do realize that programming involves using math at least sometimes, right?  And in this particular case, mathematical expressions *about* the performance of a program, seem pretty on-topic--CS courses cover this stuff, Math courses do not.

Comment: This isn't about performance of a program; it its *strictly* the growth rate of a sum. There is no code, no hint at what algorithm this might even apply to: it's a pure math problem, for which an entire site--math.stackexchange.com--exists. Even cs.stackexchange.com might be a better fit.

Comment: Summing the series is an O(n) operation. But your question is about math, not programming. Hint: if it doesn't have a line of code in some language, it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

In Big-O notation you forget about constant factors.

In your example S(n) = 1+2+...+n = n·(n+1)/2 is in O(n<sup>2</sup>) since you can find a constant number c with

> S(n) < c · n<sup>2</sup> for all n > n<sub>0</sub>

(just choose c = 1).
Notice: Big-O notation is an **upper** bound, i.e. S(n) grows not faster than n<sup>2</sup>.
Notice also, that S(n) also grows obviously not faster than n<sup>3</sup> so it is also in O(n<sup>3</sup>).

**Some additional:**

You can also proof the other way around that n<sup>2</sup> is in O(S(n)).

> n<sup>2</sup> < c·S(n) = c·n·(n+1)/2 holds for any c ≥ 2 for all n

So n<sup>2</sup> is in O(S(n)). This means both functions grow asymtoticly equal. You can wirt this as S(n) is in Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

When computing O(n) n(n-1)/2 is the same as n^2 since it has the highest complexity

Comment: complexity is basically the running time

Answer (score 0):

1+2+3+...+n Sum of this equation is n(n+1)/2 
Means it is n^2+n/2 therefore O(n^2).
Complexity,Big O will look at the biggest factor in the equation because logically it is the one that takes most time.( think of it in a computer program)